# Select where max date

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, max

I want to select the last note from notes with the following query:

```
SELECT cn.Note, MAX(cn.Date) 
       FROM CarsNote cn 
       WHERE CustomerID = '80' AND cn.Type = 'INFO'  

       GROUP BY Note
```

When I execute this query i get four results but i want only the last note.

When i do `SELECT TOP 1` I don't get the lastest note .

What is missing here?

Comment: Which database product (Oracle, SQL Server, mySql ...)?

Comment: @ ReneNyffenegger  SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no MAX or GROUP BY. It is just:

```
SELECT TOP 1 cn.Note, cn.Date
FROM CarsNote cn 
WHERE cn.CustomerID = '80' AND cn.Type = 'INFO'  
ORDER BY cn.Date desc;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 cn.Note, cn.Date as maxdate
FROM CarsNote cn 
WHERE CustomerID = '80' AND cn.Type = 'INFO'  
GROUP BY cn.Note, cn.Date
ORDER BY maxdate desc;
```